# What is this anime where people manifest special powers from element-based auras?

Tags: psychic-academy

I remember watching an anime with my friend about 9 years ago, while I wasn't taking any shows seriously. The show also has a Manga, which my friend also had. Here are some general details about the world that I can remember:

- There are people in the world with special powers manifested in an Aura.
- Every person has a unique Aura with its own special capabilities.
- Every person with an Aura can do certain basic things:

  - They can cross their arms in front of them and create a shield made of Aura. This technique is called Guarding, I believe.
  - They can do short-distance teleportation. If I remember correctly, this is a semi-advanced technique.
  - They can hold up their right-hand index finger and middle finger (like a peace sign or a V or what-have-you), and put this in front of their eyes to see through the space between their fingers. This allows them to see other peoples' Auras, if they have any. I do remember that in the Anime, there were many colors of Aura, but I am not certain if their colors represented anything meaningful.
- The people who had an Aura were taken (not necessarily by force) to a special school to foster their growth and development.
- There is tension between people with Auras and gangs and other organizations of humans without Auras.
- Auras slightly reflected a person's nature.

Those are some of the details about the world in general, and of how much of their magic system that I can remember. I do not remember any character names either, but I can give details about them as much as I can remember:

- The main character was a male, and in the beginning of the show he learns that he has an Aura, which he has not identified.
- He had a childhood friend, a girl, and they liked each other. During their childhood, she was revealed to have an Aura, so she was brought to the school I mentioned earlier, and was taken from his life. Her Aura was Water, and she uses her Water Aura to heal people by making little water clones of herself that wash away peoples' injuries. For a good portion of the show, she is the MC's main love interest.
- Not long in the show, the main character meets another girl through an interesting event: A mother holding her baby while standing on a balcony accidentally drops her baby (somehow) while the MC just walked by. He turns around in response to her scream for help and reaches his hand out to the falling baby, which magically floats in the air for about a second, just enough time for this girl character to teleport into the air and catch the baby. This girl had red hair and her Aura was called "Burning Rose" and later on in the show becomes the MC's love interest.
- The main character is not unaware of this world at all, as he has an older brother who has the Aura of Metal. His older brother is also famous in the world for some of his powers. One of those that I remember is that he can cocoon himself in metal (and possibly regenerate).

Those are some of the main protagonists of the show. Aside from them, there are some students at the school I can recall, as well as some other characters:

- There was a girl who wore glasses, and while I am not too certain about this, I believe her Aura was Wind. Her special power utilized a special crystal ball, and she used Divination with that ball to test the compatibility of two Auras. If I recall correctly, generally a really good rating from her divination is about 80% compatibility. One thing I distinctly remember is that she performed this Divination on the MC and the Burning Rose girl, and their Auras turned out to be 100% Compatible.
- There was another student, a male who wore glasses, and his Aura was Strings. I remember him because the class was having practice matches, and this particular student believed he was superior to the Burning Rose girl, so he challenged her to a duel. His strategy was to bind her with strings and attack her after she was subdued. Naturally, she burned away the bindings and defeated him.
- I do remember one of the antagonists of the show: a male scientist who was on an R&D team developing technology dealing with Auras. Primarily, they could give an Aura to someone who was not born with one, and could also change peoples' Auras. Additionally, there was a machine they developed that specifically nullified any Auras that dealt with non-organics; this seems to have been meant to defeat the Burning Rose girl, who was one of their test subjects, and the MC's older brother, whose Aura is Metal. The Scientist gave himself an Aura of Plants, so that he could take advantage of the Machine's configuration.
- I believe the main antagonist of the show was another teenage male, whose relation to the MC I cannot recall. Either way, he was another test subject of the aforementioned Scientists, who gave him an interesting Aura of Gravity, with side-effects. One such effect that develops later in the show is an automatic gravity that pulled in others' life energy. This particular power killed someone very close to him while he was unaware of it. He realizes what he is doing when he brings flowers to her funeral, and when a Scientist explains it to him the Scientist points out that the flowers he brought are now dead. He reacts by grabbing the Scientist by the shoulder, where he absorbs some of the Scientist's life energy and understands what he has done.

I believe that is everything I can remember about it. Sorry about the long post!

Comment: What do you mean by wasn't "taking any shows seriously"?

Comment: @Pacerier I never payed any real attention to the plot of a show if it had one, and I only watched episodes that happened to be on TV, so I only got a sporadic list of episodes with no context. Imagine watching only a few random episodes of One Piece, and in a random order, without any prior knowledge from the show. It'd be really difficult to understand what's going on at any given time. Because of that, I never really cared about the shows I barely understood. Now that I understand what was actually going on, and now that I can go and find every episode, I can take the shows seriously.

Comment: Why did you even watch then last time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably looking for [*Psychic Academy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychic_Academy)

[image: Episode 1]

> Psychic Academy follows the life of Ai Shiomi, a boy with psychic powers, also known as "aura power" in modern day Japan. This ability has emerged in the world, but not all people have it. Aura power itself allows certain elements such as fire, water, ice, wind, lightning, earth, and light to be used by those who have the ability. Which type of power they can use depends on their aura and what they are taught.

Comment: The moment I laid my eyes on those images, things started flooding back into me. Namely the beach, and its importance. Character names, and exact powers and things. Also, the (girl?) who has a split personality. She's quite a scary one. Many thanks for helping me find this again!